# Areas names are being prepended to URLs in javascript in .NET Core 3.1. Not sure how to get around it

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have a small bit of javascript to pass s variable called environment to my home controller. Every attempt to go directly to the Home controller is prepending the Area from the controller I am in.

This is on my _Layout page in a dropdown at the top. I am trying to navigate back to the home page any time the environment dropdown is changed.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlEnvironment").change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var url = "~/Areas/General/Home/Index?environment=" + $this.val();
        location = url;
    });

});
</script>
```

This is the dropdown

```
            <div>
            <text style="font-weight:500">Environment</text> <br /> @Html.DropDownList("Environment", Helpers.SelectListItemHelper.GetEnvironmentSelectList(), null, new { @class = "form-control ays-ignore", @id = "ddlEnvironment", @style = "min-width: 120px; margin-right:10px; cursor:pointer;" })
        </div>
```

Other links in my nav bar work like this, but making my javascript similar is still adding the Area to the URL, making it go to a non-existent page.

```
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Core/Organizations">Organizations</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Union/OrgUnits">Org Units</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Union/Locations">Locations</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Union/Users">Users</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Core/Devices">Devices</a>
```

Every attempt to load the page with my url it is adding "localhost:5432/[NameOfArea]" to the front of the URL. I should be able to go directly to a url (like localhost:5432/General/Home/Index?environment), but something is adding the area to the beginning of my urls. Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So it's going to be one of those. I didnt change anything and it magically works now. I will take it, I guess.